Conditional type props based on other props with mandatory props
I've got a discriminated union type that allows certain props based on another prop in the type. Trying to add a mandatory field to the union seems to be breaking the type-checking that was working before.
I've got the following types:
type ColType = 'string' | 'array';

// Base type for all columns - makes sure the field is valid
type DataGridColDefBase<C extends ColType, F extends boolean> = {
  type?: C;
  filterable?: F;
};

// Type that makes the 'type' prop optional
type DataGridColDefNoType<C extends ColType = ColType, F extends boolean = boolean>
  = DataGridColDefBase<C, F> &
  { type?: never; filterable?: F };

// Type used for columns that have operators that take no parameters - these don't need to be specified when used
type DataGridColDefNoParameterOperator<C extends ColType = ColType, F extends boolean = boolean>
  = DataGridColDefBase<C, F> &
  (
    | { type: C extends 'string' ? C : never; filterable?: F extends true ? F : never; filterOperators?: () => void; }
    | { type: C extends 'string' ? C : never; filterable?: F extends false ? F : never; }
  );

// Type used for columns that have operators that take parameters - those need to be specified when used
type DataGridColDefParameterOperator<C extends ColType = ColType, F extends boolean = boolean>
  = DataGridColDefBase<C, F> &
  (
    | { type: C extends 'array' ? C : never; filterable?: F extends true ? F : never; filterOperators: () => void; }
    | { type: C extends 'array' ? C : never; filterable?: F extends false ? F : never; }
  );

type TypeSafeGridColDef<C extends ColType = ColType, F extends boolean = boolean>
  =
  | DataGridColDefNoType<C, F>
  | DataGridColDefNoParameterOperator<C, F>
  | DataGridColDefParameterOperator<C, F>;

This is correctly throwing an error that type is missing when I try to define a variable without it:
const test: TypeSafeGridColDef = { filterOperators: () => [] };

// Error: Property 'type' is missing in type '{ filterOperators: () => never[]; }' but required in type '{ type: "array"; filterable?: true | undefined; filterOperators: () => void; }'.

See a full example playground with more tests here.
I then add another prop field to DataGridColDefBase, which I want to be mandatory in all cases and I pass the new generic through all types that are affected:
type GridValidRowModel = { [key: string]: any; [key: symbol]: any; };

type FieldDef<R extends GridValidRowModel> = keyof R;

// Base type for all columns - makes sure the field is valid
type DataGridColDefBase<R extends GridValidRowModel, C extends ColType, F extends boolean> = {
  field: FieldDef<R>;
  type?: C;
  filterable?: F;
};

The test same test from above now stops giving me that error:
const test: TypeSafeGridColDef<{ bar: string }> = { field: 'bar', filterOperators: () => [] };

// No error

See a the same example playground from before but with the extra field here.
What I've tried so far
I don't think this is anything to do with the field type per se - I've tried having a simple field: string instead and not using a generic and I get the same behaviour.
I've also tried putting the field prop inside all the union types with the same effect.
This line of thinking has further pushed me into thinking if this entire discriminated union approach is the right way to go, so suggestions on that one are welcome too!

This is a lot more complicated than it should be to be a [mre]. Why go through all the complicated conditional types instead of just writing out your final discriminated union? Can't you give us a [mre] we can look at simply, like this? I mean, what's the goal of asking the question with the conditional types that isn't better served by my stripped down example? Maybe I'm confused? Please [edit] to clarify.

If I'm right about the [mre], then you've got a bad union member. You don't want { type?: never; filterable?: F }. You want { type?: never; filterable?: F; filterOperators?: never } which actually enforces the constraint you care about. Your first case just "lucks out" because it's a weak type and you get excess property checking. But you can't ever rely on such checking. If you want to prohibit a property, do it explicitly. Does that answer the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks for the answer @jcalz! I think this is exactly what I am after - seems to be passing all my tests. Was not familiar with the concept of weak types, will do some extra reading on that. Thanks for the feedback too. I started with something even more complicated - taken from a repo I'm working on and has 10 different type cases with different properties, so I thought stripping it down to 2 and providing comments for context would be enough but you're right that it could be even more minimal.

What I am not 100% sure about though is if all and any extra props need to be added to the same constraint type (DataGridColDefNoType) or do they need to be in their own types.
So for example, if I had another "actions" type that needed its own special actionsOperators prop, would I just have one constraint { type?: never; filterable?: F; filterOperators?: never; actionOperators?: never } or would there need to be two types added to the union like { type?: never; filterable?: F; filterOperators?: never } | { type?: never; filterable?: F; actionOperators?: never }?

Probably just one. But I'd need a [mre] to be sure. I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

The issue is that you've got a union member of the form
{
  type?: undefined;
  filterable?: boolean | undefined;
} 

in the first case and
{
  field: string;
  type?: undefined;
  filterable?: boolean | undefined;
} 

in the second. Both of those are incredibly wide types that match just about anything, even things you don't want.  In the first case, though, TypeScript sees that all the properties are optional and performs weak type detection on it, meaning it enforces excess property checking even though that is not really a type safety issue.  Technically, { filterOperators: () => [] } matches, but weak types are given extra scrutiny.
In the second case, it's not a weak type because of the required field property, and it therefore matches { field: 'bar', filterOperators: () => [] } and there is no complaint.
I suspect you really want that union member to look like { type?: never; filterable?: F; filterOperators?: never } so that filterOpterators is prohibited when type is absent. But that is up to you to decide. Don't rely on excess property checking to enforce these things, because excess property checking is more of a linter feature and not a type safety feature.
Playground link to code
